# Return specific data from external api using Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm a little bit stuck when calling an external api using RestTemplate, as my request is returning a string. I'm from a js background so with js I would just return json and extract what I need.

I only want to get the stock info for the current day (2020-02-07), I don't want meta data etc

My code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
return result;
```

Code returns this:

```
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "XYL",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-02-07",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-02-07": {
            "1. open": "83.3600",
            "2. high": "84.9100",
            "3. low": "83.1300",
            "4. close": "84.2000",
            "5. volume": "2495921"
        },
        "2020-02-06": {
            "1. open": "81.0000",
            "2. high": "83.3100",
            "3. low": "80.8000",
            "4. close": "83.1200",
            "5. volume": "5052421"
        }
```

I only want my request to return current day:

```
"2020-02-07": {
            "1. open": "83.3600",
            "2. high": "84.9100",
            "3. low": "83.1300",
            "4. close": "84.2000",
            "5. volume": "2495921"
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a pojo class so you can consume the returned JSON and have it mapped into Java instances.

For example if you have something like:

```
public class TimeSeriesDaily{
    @JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> dailyValues; 
}
```

You could then use this with RestTemplate like this:

```
TimeSeriesDaily result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, TimeSeriesDaily.class);
```

This reference might also be useful: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/